# Unable to connect two different database with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

I have two different config file for two different database and each one of them as there sessions open. Below is the code.

FYI - for security reasons i removed all my credential and have dummy one placed in my config files

one.cfg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD      3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">URL</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">userName</property>
    <property name="connection.password">Password</property>
    <mapping class="com.ClassNameOfTheTable" />
      </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Second.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD   3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">url</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">userName</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<mapping class="com.tableClassName" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateStratApp class(where i set the configured file)

```
 package com.tn.gov;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.hibernate.Transaction;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

  public class HibernateStartApp  {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory1();
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory1 = buildSessionFactory2();
Session session=null;
Transaction transaction = null;


private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory1() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration().configure("one.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactoryOne() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactoryTwo(){
    return sessionFactory1;
}
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory2() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure("two.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

}

And by opening and closing sessions i am retrieving the values.

But i am geting failed.org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect when i try to connect.

Comment: Is it correct that one config contains "hibernate" prefix in property names ant other does not? It seems to me that your code contains lapses.

Answer (score 0):

i could able to figure this out, It was the problem with the URL which i was pointing to, That weird, that the error message dint printed it out correct.